# Proving that the set of all graphs of continuous functions $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the set of all graphs of continuous functions $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{G} := \{ G_f : f \in \mathbb R^{[0,1]}  \ \text{is continuous} \}
\end{align*}
where $G_f := \{(x,f(x)) : x \in [0,1] \} \subset \mathbb R^2$.

Then $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$, with $\mathcal{F}$ being the set of all non-empty bounded and closed subsets of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Let $(\mathcal{F}, h)$ be the metric space equiped with the Hausdorff metric.


Now, how do I prove that $\mathcal{G}$ is closed in $(\mathcal{F}, h)$?
I have already proven the fact that every graph $G_f \in \mathcal{G}$ is closed and bounded for the euclidean metric. One way to prove the closeness of $\mathcal{G}$ is by showing that every convergent sequence $(G_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathcal{G}$ (with metric $h$) has a limit in $\mathcal{G}$, meaning that every convergent sequence of graphs of continous functions on $[0,1]$ is also the graph of a continous function on $[0,1]$.

However, I cannot seem to find the function to which the graphs converge to. For that I think I need to prove that the functions $f_n$ of the graphs $G_n$ converge to some continuous function $f$ by using the convergence of the graphs under the metric $h$, but I have no clue on how to find a connection between these two convergences. Some starting point would be nice.

Thanks in regards !

Comment: By the closed graph theorem a compact subset $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ is a graph of some continuous function $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $D\cap(\{x\}\times\mathbb{R})$ is empty for $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash[0,1]$ and has exactly one point otherwise. You can utilize this to show that sequence of graphs has to converge to a graph.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? I would imagine $\{0\}\times[0,1]\cup [0,1]\times\{0\}$ is in the closure, while obviously not a graph itself...

Comment: @Cronus , yes you are right ! Actually, the question in my book was not " prove that $\mathcal{G}$ is closed", but rather " is $\mathcal{G}$ closed ?", so my apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{G}$ is not closed because there exists a convergent sequence of graphs of continous functions that do not converge to the graph of a continous function. For example, take $f_n(x) = -nx + 1$ for $x \in [0, 1/n]$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ for $x \in ]1/n , 1]$. These functions are all continuous, but the sequence of graphs $G_{n}$ converge to $G = \{0\}\times[0,1]\cup [0,1]\times\{0\}$, which is not the graph of a continuous function (it is not even the graph of a function).